# Show Shipping cost in checkout page not in cart page

Tags: checkout, cart, shipping, magento-1.9.3.2

I am using Magento 1.9.3.2.

I need customization like, `Shipping cost` should not show in the `Cart page`, but shown in the `Checkout page`.

Is possible to make like `Shipping cost` should be calculated only in `checkout page`, not in the `Cart page` even user logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created a `event` with `observer`. Here is the Code:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_save_before>
            <observers>
            <your_module_shipping_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Your_Module/observer</class>
                <method>setFreeShipping</method>
            </your_module_shipping_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_save_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Observer function `setFreeShipping` Code:

```
public function setFreeShipping($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $cart = $event->getCart();
    $shippingaddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingaddress->setShippingMethod('')->save();
    return;
}
```

Reference and credits: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203474/shipping-costs-remove-in-cart-grand-total-in-magento-1-9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code somewhere when cart loads:

```
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_all');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nominal');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nonnominal');
$quote->collectTotals();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sukumar.  I have added thid code in `template/checkout/cart.phtml`. But It is not working.

Comment: Try to reload the page again. You need to call that code before page renders.

Comment: Shall i call in the `checkout/cart` action?

Comment: I used this solution, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203474/shipping-costs-remove-in-cart-grand-total-in-magento-1-9. It worked in `checkout_cart_save_before` event.

Comment: Great!. You can use both code for unset shipping method.