# Shipping costs remove in cart grand total in magento 2.2.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cart

How to remove Shipping costs in cart grand total in magento2.1.7. I just need to remove the shipping price value from summary in cart. After returning from checkout to cart page the shipping price value shows in cart page(Summary).
It will be very confusing for the user when returning back to cart page.
I referred this link [Shipping costs remove in cart grand total in magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203474/shipping-costs-remove-in-cart-grand-total-in-magento-1-9)

But the above link is in Magento1.9. I want in Magento2.1.7

[image]

The above screenshot is in cart page without shipping price calculation.

[image]

The above screenshot is after returning from checkout page it shows with shipping calculation in cart page.
I need to remove the shipping calculation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113144/magento-2-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-from-cart

Comment: The link you shared is to remove shipping method but the shipping calculation remains in the cart after returning from checkout page.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?